# How many unique combinations with $7$ digits can be formed in which there are $2$ sets of repeating numbers with the size $2$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, factorial

Example: $[1,1,2,2,3,4,5]$. How many unique combinations are there? I started off with $7!$ but there is going to be repeated values so I decided to try and narrow it down but I kept getting stuck.

Comment: By combinations, do you mean sequences?

Comment: As you can see from the answers provided (and the comment above), your question is ambigious. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to chose the two digits that will be duplicated, and then $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to choose the remaining three digits, so $\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{3}$ combinations.

Comment: The question is poorly worded.  I suspect the OP wants to count sequences of length $7$ in which two of the digits have multiplicity $2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Perhaps, but he did say "combinations," and his example looks more like a multiset than a sequence to me.  Hard to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to divide by $2$ for double-counting the sequences with the $1$'s swapped, and also divide by $2$ for double-counting the sequences with the $2$'s swapped. Hence, you get:

$$\frac{7!}{2 \cdot 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don’t mean sequences, i.e. if we have {1,1,2,2,3,4,5}={1,2,1,3,2,5,4} then you have $\binom{10}{2}$ ways to choose the repeating digits. Then you can choose the other three digits in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways. Total =$\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{3}=45\cdot 84 =3780$.

 If, however the order matters, then multiply it by another $\frac{7!}{2!2!}$ to account for the repetitions. Hence the answer in this case is $1260\cdot 3780 = \binom{8}{3} \binom{10}{2} \frac{7!}{2!2!} $